# MAMP.app & .htaccess - Can't override after config

Tags: htaccess

For whatever reason I can't seem to get my .htaccess file to work correctly on a local Wordpress install. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the themes assets paths rewritten as such:

```
 RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ wp-content/themes/cashed/img/$1 [L]
```

The current location to my images folder is:

```
 wp-content/themes/cashed/img
```

and I'd like to change it to be

```
 img/
```

I've read a [few](http://trevordavis.net/blog/use-htaccess-files-with-mamp) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp) about having to configure MAMP to allow for .htaccess files and I feel like I've configured them correctly.

I've edited the file: applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf to have the following rules:

```
 <Directory />
     Options All
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all 
 </Directory>
```

I've also restarted MAMP.app as well as my machine many times and for whatever reason I feel that MAMP is ignoring this .htaccess file which is stored in the root directory of my WP install.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your default `<Directory />` settings aren't getting overridden somewhere else?

I have mine directly in the vhost and .htaccess and rewrite rules work fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wp.project
    DocumentRoot "/Users/chris/Sites/wp.project"

    <Directory "/Users/chris/Sites/wp.project">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RewriteBase in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteBase /siteyourworkingon/
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Was already set to RewriteBase /